# Share files with other collaborators in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I know that I can access my google drive files from colab with a code like this:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

But in this way, only me is able to access data file located on my drive. If I share my colab notebook with someone, how can he/she access to that file? Obviously above code is not applicable for him/her, because he does can't access my account to authorize colab.

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 ways.

1. You share the folder with him. He click the folder and choose "Add to My Drive". It will create a symlink (it won't copy, won't take space). He can now mount it the same way as you, using `drive.mount(..)`.
2. Share the folder with him. Then access the folder and files within using pydrive, not drive.mount(). You must use the FILE_ID instead of file names to refer to those folder and files.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to share permissions of shared folders, in this case other users can edit, comment. or view shared folders, for that:

1. Go to [drive.google.com](http://drive.google.com)
2. Select the folder that you want to change owners.
3. Click share at the top right
4. Click **Advanced**
5. To the right of the person's name Click **Is Owner**, and then save changes

Comment: But the problem is how he can mount this folder to his colab VM?

Comment: Once the files are shared in the drive of your collaborators they are able to mount the drive using the same command drive.mount('/content/drive')