# Google Colab: Import data from google drive and make it possible to share it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm currently working on a project I want to share with others without them giving them full acess to my drive, which Google aks for anytime I use:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I want to be able to share a folder with a jupyter notebook and the containing data in subfolders (in google drive itself or just by sending them the files, whichever is easier to solve). I want them being able to use it without correcting the path to their drive, needing them to give acess to my or their drive or something like that.
I know this is possible in normal jupyter notebooks (just sharing the folder with the notebook and data and it just takes the data by simply setting the working directory to the folder it is in and then using relative paths), but the same code won't work in google colab.

Is there maybe a way to link data (in this case images) to a Google Colab notebook?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: do you want to share a Jupyter Notebook, files from Google Drive for its execution as well as the resulting files from Notebook's execution?

Comment: not the resulting files, but the notebook and the files it needs, so everybody can use the notebook

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59527907/7789963

Comment: Thank you, that might help. I'll try it out and come back if I know more

Comment: Thanks @medium-dimensional , I took a while to figure out how pydrive works, but I got it now :)
Thank you a lot 

PS: is there a way to link the solution to the other question? I don't know how

Comment: Glad to know! If the answer from any other question worked for you which also asked to resolve a similar problem, please share its link here. Your question can be then marked as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) which we'll help others find out the right answer. :)

Comment: I would just link the answer you linked before:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59527907/7789963

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share files with other collaborators in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517960/share-files-with-other-collaborators-in-google-colab)

Comment: Thanks! This might get flagged as duplicate and redirect others to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

after this command, you have to provide your file directory which you already uploaded to your GoogleDrive.

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')

directory = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME'
```

The "directory" of your folder should be directed like mentioned above order...